# Apche Solr and Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

7

I want to create a search box in my web app using Apache Solr.I am using mongoDB as database and collecting the data using web scrapping

As I new to these concepts (solr) I am struggling with this.

can any one help me on this?

I already installed and configured apache Solr .Now I dont know how to start with this.
How to index the data from database.